# Office 365 IMAP Access - PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I've got a script that basically access email through IMAP and then finds all the .wav audio and download them into a folder locally on the server.

I'm struggling to get it to access Office 365 through IMAP.

Keeps saying Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox.

&

Cannot connect to {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX: Too many login failures

See whole script below;

```
<?php

    $MSG_DIR = "D:/Voicemail/Messages/";

    $USER = "xx";

    $PASS = "xx";



    // connect to JARVIS


    echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:#2471b6'>Connecting to J.A.R.V.I.S.</div>\n<br/>";


    $host = "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox";

    $mbox=imap_open($host,$USER,$PASS, NULL, 1, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI')) or die("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());



    // Look over mailbox

    echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:#2471b6'>Connection Complete...</div>\n<br/>";

    $MC = imap_check($mbox) or die("Can't check for messages");



    $overview = imap_fetch_overview( $mbox, "1:".$MC->Nmsgs, 0 ) or die( "Can't get headers");

    $countThis = 0;

    foreach ( $overview as $email )

    {       

        $subject = $email->subject;

        $udate = $email->udate;

        if( preg_match('/Voice Message from ([0-9]+)/', $subject, $groups) ||
        preg_match('/Voice Message from ([a-zA-Z]\w+)/', $subject, $groups) )

        {

            $filename = $MSG_DIR."/".$groups[1].date(" d-m H-i-s", $udate).".wav";



            if( file_exists( $filename ) )

            {

                echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#000000'>Skipping $filename...</div>\n";

            }

            else

            {

                echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#000000'>Extracting $filename...</div>\n";

                 $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mbox,$email->uid, FT_UID) or die( "could not fetch structure");



                 foreach ( $structure->parts as $part )


                 {

                    if( $part->subtype == "X-WAV" || $part->subtype=="WAV" || $part->subtype=="OCTET-STREAM")


                    {

                        // found it!

                        $body = imap_base64( imap_fetchbody( $mbox, $email->uid, 2, FT_UID ) ) or die( "Could not fetch part");

                        file_put_contents( $filename, $body );

                    }

                    else

                    {

                    }

                 }

            }

            $countThis++;

        }

    }

    echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:#2471b6'></br>Found $countThis Voicemails\r\n</div>";

    echo "<div style ='font:11px/21px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;font-weight: bold;color:#ff0000'></br>Disconnecting from J.A.R.V.I.S.\r\n</div>";



    imap_close($mbox);  

?>
```

This was previously used on Exchange 2010.

Hope someone can help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

FIXED!

It was the password.

PHP doesn't like $ in the password it would seem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in PHP the variables are declared with the symbol $. And PHP interprets the content of the strings declared with double quotes "". If you have:

```
$foo = "var";
```

and you do:

```
echo "$foo";
```

You will get ***var***. However if you use the single quote '', PHP will not interpret the content:

```
$foo = "var";
echo '$foo';
```

It will return ***$foo*** literally.
As a small note I add that at the time of execution it is faster to use the single quote because PHP does not have to interpret it, but in this case you will not be able to use variables within the chain.
A greeting.